# MVVM MediatorLiveData observer onchanged called multiple times

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I am using MVVM + LiveData + Dagger 2.11 on my app.On SignInFragment click on a textview send request to server and show respopnse on snackbar. It works fine on first time click of textview.If I click again,it sends request(inbetween shows snackbar response message here) and ViewModel MediatorLiveData observer onChanged method called muliple times.Is it default behaviour of MediatorLiveData?

**SignInViewModel.java**

```
public class SignInViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    @Inject
    MediatorLiveData mediatorLiveData;

    @Inject
    SnackbarMessage mSnackbarTextLiveData = new SnackbarMessage();

    @Inject
    public SignInViewModel(Application application,SignInRepository signInRepository) {
        super(application);
        this.signInRepository = signInRepository;
    }

    public MediatorLiveData<ResendActivationCodeResponse> resendActivationCode(final String phoneNumber, final String countryCode) {
        final MutableLiveData<NetworkResponse> connectViaPhoneResponseMutableLiveData = signInRepository.resendActivationCode(phoneNumber, countryCode);

        mediatorLiveData.addSource(connectViaPhoneResponseMutableLiveData, new NetworkResponseObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Object data) {
                mediatorLiveData.setValue(data);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBadRequest(Object data, String errorMessage) {
                mSnackbarTextLiveData.setValue(errorMessage);
            }

            @Override
            public void onUnAuthorisedError(Object data) {
                mSnackbarTextLiveData.setValue(data.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Object data, String errorMessage) {
                mSnackbarTextLiveData.setValue(errorMessage);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNoNetworkAvailable(Object data, String errorMessage) {
                mSnackbarTextLiveData.setValue(data.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoading(Object data) {

            }
        });
        return mediatorLiveData;
    }
}
```

**SignInFragment.java**

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mSignInViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(mActivity, mViewModelFactory).get(SignInViewModel.class);
        setupSnackbar();
    }

    private void setupSnackbar() {
        mSignInViewModel.getSnackbarMessage().observe(this, new SnackbarMessage.SnackbarObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onNewMessage(String snackbarMessage) {
                ActivityUtils.showSnackbar(getView(), snackbarMessage);
            }
        });
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.resend_activation_code_textview)
    public void reSendActivationCode() {
        showProgress(true);

        final MediatorLiveData<ResendActivationCodeResponse> resendActivationCodeResponseMediatorLiveData = mSignInViewModel.resendActivationCode(mPhoneNumber, mCountryCode);


        Observer<ResendActivationCodeResponse> resendActivationCodeResponseObserver = new Observer<ResendActivationCodeResponse>() {

            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable ResendActivationCodeResponse resendActivationCodeResponse) {
                if (resendActivationCodeResponse != null) {
                    showProgress(false);
                    ActivityUtils.showSnackbar(getView(), activationCodeResentMessage);
                    //resendActivationCodeResponseMediatorLiveData.removeObserver(this);
                }
            }
        };


        resendActivationCodeResponseMediatorLiveData.observe(PhoneNumberActivationFragment.this, resendActivationCodeResponseObserver);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please help me with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60078980/how-can-i-make-separate-code-on-onchanged-while-observing-with-livedata-in-mvv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're calling `addSource` with different `LiveData` associated with different phone numbers every time your `resend_activation_code_textview` is clicked. These different `LiveData` sources are also all associated with different `NetworkResponseObservers`, that call `setValue()`. `setValue()` is what updates your listening fragments and what is what is called too many times.

**I believe the issue is because you call `addSource` every time resend_activation_code_textview is clicked and you never remove any sources.**

If you click `resend_activation_code_textview` 10 times, your `mediatorLiveData` will have 10 different sources, when you probably only wanted one.

When a source is added, it does an initial trigger of your `mediatorLiveData`, so you will always trigger `setValue()` at least once. When any of the 10 added sources are updated, it will also update your `mediatorLiveData`, and call `setValue()`. Depending on what `signInRepository.resendActivationCode` does and if it updates any of the other 10 LiveData sources, this will trigger multiple `setValue()` calls for one click.

---

There's a [removeSource()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData.html#addSource(android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData%3CS%3E,%20android.arch.lifecycle.Observer%3CS%3E)) method which you could call to make sure you never have more than one source at a time, this likely getting rid of the multiple onChanged calls. But there's a built in solution for what I think you're trying to do (which uses MediatorLiveData under the hood) -- it's the **[switchMap Transformation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations.html#switchMap(android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData%3CX%3E,%20android.arch.core.util.Function%3CX,%20android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData%3CY%3E%3E))**.

`switchMap` allows you to change the underlying source that a `LiveData` is listening to, without updating the observers. So instead of clicking `resend_activation_code_textview` 10 times and adding 10 different sources, you can have it so that every time you click `resend_activation_code_textview` the previous source will be **swapped** for a new source.

The example scenario for `switchMap` is that you have a method to look up a `userById()`. You make a normal LiveData to store the user id, and then use the `switchMap` transformation so that you have another LiveData for the current user. As the id changes, the current user is swapped out and updated:

```
MutableLiveData userIdLiveData = ...;
 LiveData userLiveData = Transformations.switchMap(userIdLiveData, id ->
     repository.getUserById(id));

 void setUserId(String userId) {
      this.userIdLiveData.setValue(userId);
 }
```

I think you're doing something similar with the phone number and country code. This is like your "id". You'll want to create an object which contains a phone number and country code, let's call it `FullPhoneNumber`. Then you'll make a `LiveData<FullPhoneNumber> phoneNumberLiveData`, which is similar to the `userIdLiveData` in the previous example. Then:

```
LiveData<ResendActivationCodeResponse> reactivationLiveData = 
Transformations.switchMap(phoneNumberLiveData, currentPhoneNumber ->
     signInRepository.resendActivationCode(currentPhoneNumber.getNumber(), currentPhoneNumber.getCountryCode());
```

Hope that helps or at least points you in the right direction!

Comment: I have a use case where the observer does not seem to fire (update) after the first time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57650511/android-recyclerviews-cardview-not-showing-every-time  Would anything from your solution above help in my case?  I would appreciate any thoughts you could offer...

Comment: Can you please help me with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60078980/how-can-i-make-separate-code-on-onchanged-while-observing-with-livedata-in-mvv

Comment: This issue ruined 2 hours of my life and then I came across this answer. Thumbs up!